# xelatex has stopped working / DVI to pdf Converter has stopped working

Tags: xetex, miktex, texniccenter, dvi, output

to create my pdf document with latex i use  TeXnicCenter on windows 7 and after i update Miketex i got this crash

[image]

```
  Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: miktex-xdvipdfmx.exe
  Application Version:  2.9.6100.0
  Application Timestamp:    58142abd
  Fault Module Name:    MiKTeX209-packagemanager.dll
  Fault Module Version: 2.9.6100.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   58157d91
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 0003ac4c
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1036
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

[image]

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: xelatex.exe
  Application Version:  0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    58142f5d
  Fault Module Name:    MiKTeX209-packagemanager.dll
  Fault Module Version: 2.9.6100.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   58157d91
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 0003ac4c
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1036
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Comment: In november quite a number of packages have been reorganized, perhaps you are missing some vital files. Open the package manager (admin), synchronize (menu repositories) and check if there are new packages.

Comment: this happened to me when i inserted png files that were longer than the 11 inch page length.  removing the graphics that spanned two pages solved the problem